# fopen and sync with disk

Tags: c++, struct, io, fopen, fwrite

I wrote a program that it must write struct to binary file and read from it.
I use fread, fwrite , fopen , fseek and fclose.
I wrote the following function that prints all of record in my file.

```
void ReadFile::printList(){
//  clearerr(bookFilePtr);

    fseek(bookFilePtr,0L,SEEK_SET); // set to begin of file

    int counter = 1;
    long int line = 1;
    int pageCounter = 1;

    while (this->readFromFile() == 1){
        string output;
        mvprintw(++line, 27,"***Title*****************Value*********" );
        output = "Name:               " + bookPtrObj->name;
        mvprintw(++line, 27, output.data());
        output = "Publisher:          " + bookPtrObj->publisher;
        mvprintw(++line, 27,output.data());
        output = "Author:             " + bookPtrObj->author;
        mvprintw(++line, 27,output.data());
        output = "Translator:         " + bookPtrObj->translator;
        if (bookPtrObj->translation == true )
            mvprintw(++line, 27,output.data());
        if (bookPtrObj->stock != true )
            mvprintw(++line, 27,"Stock:              The given book doesn't exist.");
        else
            mvprintw(++line, 27,"Stock:              The given book exist.");
        if ( pageCounter % 3 == 0){
            mvprintw(++line, 27,"Press any key to see next page...");
            getch();
            clear();
            line = 1;

        }
        pageCounter++;
        refresh();
        fseek(bookFilePtr, counter * sizeof(struct book) ,SEEK_SET); // seek to next data
        counter ++;
    }
//  fflush(bookFilePtr);

    menu();
}
```

**Note:** I run for first and data entry, i can see my data from above func very nice and page to page.But when i exit program , everything are broken.When i run for second time, and run above function, i get **Segmentation fault**, I trace it , bookPtrObj that it is pointer of my struct, can't read my file.I try with type of fopen, [rb. wb, ab+, rb+ , a+, w+ ,aw+]  and so on. but i didn't get result.
I write to file with the following lines, Of course  i fill element of struct and then run the 2 following lines :

```
fseek(bookFilePtr,0L,SEEK_END);
fwrite(ptr,sizeof(struct book),1,bookFilePtr);
```

How do i to stay my data in file?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided a whole lot of code, but my guess is that you save pointers to strings, not strings themselves, or even worse (or is it worse?) — `std::string` object content. You need to serialize them properly instead.

Comment: If your guess is true, Why i can data entry for first run? and read correctly?

Comment: Did I understand you right that you can read correctly while in the same instance you used to write the data?

Comment: A file is a series of bytes. To write data to a file, you must convert it into a series of bytes that expresses the data. When you read it back, you must convert it from the format of the series of bytes you wrote to the file to the format you need it in to manipulate it. You never do either of those things. You *cannot* do this: `fwrite(ptr,sizeof(struct book),1,bookFilePtr);`. You *have to* convert it into the format the file is supposed to be in.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to write data to a file or read data from a file, you should write out a specification for the format the data in the file will have. What you're doing is writing out arbitrary bytes of data in an unknown format to a file. If that actually works, it's only by luck.

If you want to store, say, an integer, in a file, you need to decide whether you'll used a fixed-length or a variable-length. If variable, how will the reader determine how many bytes it occupies? Will the most significant digits/bits come first or the least significant? Will you write it in text or binary?

You then need to write code to convert your data into the bytes the file is supposed to have. And when you read them back, you need to convert them into the types your program wants to use to manipulate them.

If you're not experienced, lines of text are probably best. That way, you can also easily look at the file in a viewer or editor to make sense of it.

You cannot do this:

```
fwrite(ptr,sizeof(struct book),1,bookFilePtr);
```

You're just writing arbitrary bytes to the file. Yes, they make sense in your current execution context, but they may or may not make sense in another execution context. You need to convert them into a well-defined, self-contained data format suitable to writing to a file.

Here's a silly example way:

```
const char *foo="foo";
fwrite(&foo, sizeof(&foo), 1, filePtr);
```

This will write out the contents of `foo`, which is a pointer to a string that has the value `"foo"`. But when you read that back, you read back a pointer to an address space that no longer even exists. What sense can you make of that? It's not very likely to point to anything meaningful in your address space.

Comment: You mean `fwrite(&foo,sizeof(foo),1,filePtr);` I presume. (the `&` bit).

Comment: Ack, you're right. I "fixed" it, but it makes my example a terrible example.

Comment: I don't think you should `sizeof(&foo)`. You need the size of the `foo` variable, not pointer to it. Though, since it *is* a pointer, it's the same. So well, it "works" :)

Comment: Dear David, Your notices very importance and it change all of my program, very very thank you, but i have  question : i decided to use constant length for structure , and Michael in more above said i need to use serialization, which is better ? i don't know about serialization.

Comment: "Serialization" just means converting a structure into a sequence of bytes in a defined way. Fixed length structures are easier to work with.

Comment: Yes, My structure's fields using string instead char *.